Why is the strain tensor of a rod under uniform torsion the same everywhere along the rod?
I'm currently reading the section on torsion of rods in "Theory of Elasticity" by Landau and Lifshitz (3rd. Ed., Chapter 2). If we suppose that the rod is cylindrical with radius $R$ and the twist rate per unit length is $\tau$, then, if we consider a small section of the rod and assume $\tau R \ll 1$, the displacement vector of a point can be derived using
$$d\mathbf{r} = d\hat{\phi}\times \mathbf{r}. \quad (1)$$
The x and y components of the displacement vector are
$$u_{x} = -\tau z y, \quad u_{y} = \tau z x, \quad u_{z}=0,$$
if we ignore displacements along z. From this the strain tensor components can be derived as
$$u_{xx} = u_{yy} = u_{zz} = u_{xy} = u_{yx} = 0,$$
$$u_{xz} = u_{zx} = -\frac{1}{2}\tau y, \quad u_{yz}= u_{zy} = \frac{1}{2}\tau x.$$
My question is: Why is it true that this is the value of the strain tensor everywhere along the rod? In the derivation we used (1) which is only true for small displacement angles with respect to the coordinate system within the small rod section, i.e. its only true for the small rod section we considered. If the rod is long (large $z$), then the points at the end of the rod will have large displacements.
The way I explain this to myself is that we can portion the rod into many sections along $z$ and consider each section only deformed with respect to the one before it. (After all, strain is defined only where there is deformation). Then this result makes sense, but now we don't have a unique coordinate system with respect to which to measure $z$. When we move from one small section to the next we need to reset the $z$ coordinate so that Eq. (1) is valid... That is, we now have a new coordinate system located within the new rod section... Is my way of thinking about it correct? What am I missing?

Axial $z$-coordinate is homogeneous (and thus the solution doesn't depend on $z$) for:

slender beams, if one excludes the region close to the extreme sections of the beam;
with no distributed loads along the span of the beam.

These are the assumptions of de Saint-Venant beam model. You can find some notes about beam models and structural mechanics here (links in light-blue).
If these two assumptions hold, the equilibrium of the whole beam requires that torsion moments on extreme sections are equal and opposite $M(z=0) = - M(z=L)$. The indefinite equilibrium equation for the elementary chunk of the beam reads
$$\begin{aligned} 0 & = -M(z) + M(z+\Delta z) + m(z)\Delta z = 0\\
& = \left( M'(z) + m(z) \right) \Delta z + o(z) \ ,
\end{aligned} \quad \rightarrow \quad M'(z) = - m(z)$$
being $M(z)$ the internal torsion moment (as a result of the integral of the internal stresses on beam section at $z$) and $m(z)$ is the distributed torsion moment. If the distributed loads is zero, the internal torsion moment is uniform along the beam.
Since the internal stress distribution in beam models only depends on the internal loads, and strain distribution comes from the proper constitutive equation, uniform internal actions in $z$ imply uniform
stress and strain distribution in $z$

Wow, I had no idea about any of this. Thank you! So, I suppose that the derivation given in Landau is incomplete in this sense.

If you're studying structural mechanics, and beam theory in an Engineering Course, Landau Theory of Elasticity is not the best book, imho. Too much "physicist approach". It's better to start somewhere else, and come back later as a nice reading
